# Thunderbird no longer starts after upgrade to 38.3.0

Tags: linux-mint, ldap, thunderbird

After I upgraded Thunderbird last Monday to version 38.3.0 on my Mint 17.2 XFce I was no longer able to start Thunderbird.

First I made sure that the files in my profile were all owned by me. When this did not help I renamed the `~/.thunderbird` directory. Normally Thunderbird creates this directory. Not in this case.

I searched and tried the hint to use `strace -f /usr/bin/thunderbird` to see what happens. In the last 20 lines of the 6015 lines that were produced I could see that there was a problem with the LDAP.

I do the user authentication with OpenLDAP and this works correct. I can query OpenLDAP when I am logged in so I suppose that the problem is not the access to the OpenLDAP server (which is in a different server). Further searching gave some solutions that did not work:

- `touch /var/lib/libnss-ldap/bind_policy_soft`;
- Put `bind=soft` in `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf`.

I nearly had it solved when I launched the *nscd* service. Thunderbird starts and I am able to read my address book and check my calendar. No e-mails are visible and I am asked to configure my mail account. At the same time the *nscd* service is stopped. When I check the `~/thunderbird` directory I see that some files in my profile have current date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know what happened. It is now working again. There must have been something wrong with the *nscd* service. After a few days I found out that it was running again. Now I could start Thunderbird again. Unfortunately I had to re-configure my connection to my remote mail-server. After that I copied over all my folders (including my 'old' inbox under a different name) so I lost nothing.